# Чи можна гадати на Івана Купала?

Tags: вживання-слів, синоніми

На [Мова — ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/antusurzhuk/gadatu-j-vorozhutu)
зіткнулась з такою картинкою
[image]
В даному випадку показано, що *гадати* не може бути синонімом слова *ворожити*. Але в [СУМ-11](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/slovnyk_ukrainskoi_movy_v_11_tomakh/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) слово *гадати* та *ворожити* синоніми. То ж чи правильно *гадати* на Івана Купала?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В [Академічному тлумачному словнику (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghadaty) наведено такі значення дієслова *гадати*:

> **ГАДАТИ** 1, аю, аєш, недок.
>
> 1. про кого — що і без додатка. Думати, розмірковувати. //  Мріяти.
>    Гадати думу (думку, гадку) — те саме, що Думати думу
>    (думи, думку) (див. думати).
> 2. перев. з спол. що. Мати думку, міркування з якого-небудь приводу; вважати.
>    //  Передбачати, припускати.
> 3. з інфін. Мати намір що-небудь робити. //  Сподіватися.
>
> **ГАДАТИ** 2, аю, аєш, недок., ***заст***. Ворожити.

Серед російсько-українських словників знаходимо *гадати* як відповідник російському *гадать* лише у [Словарі росийсько-українському 1893–1898рр. (М.Уманець, А.Спілка.)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

Логічним висновком є такий: дієслово *гадати* у значенні *ворожити* для української мови є застарілим, тому і не рекомендується для вживання.

Answer (score 2):

Згідно із  [Словником синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) ці слова є синонімами

> **ВОРОЖИ́ТИ** (вгадувати що-небудь на картах, воску, по долоні і т. ін.), **ГАДА́ТИ** заст.;**ЗАГА́ДУВАТИ** (намагатися знайти відповідь
>   за якимись прикметами). - *Коли я була маленькою, то до нас зайшла
>   ворожка-циганка і ворожила мені, що я буду щаслива* (В. Гжицький);
>   *Пані сидить і гадає на картах* (Марко Вовчок)

У [Словник фразеологізмів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) також використовують, як синоніми

> *ба́́ба [ще] на́́двоє ворожи́́ла (гада́́ла)*. Невідомо, чи відбудеться,
>   здійсниться щось, чи ні; побачимо.

У СЛОВНИКУ УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ МОВИ ONLINE.ТОМИ 1-8. (А-МІШУ́РНИЙ) слово [***"гадати"***](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=186102&page=579) вже немає визначення "ворожити" лише перші три варіанти з [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghadaty).

***Тому краще розмежувати ці два слова та надати перевагу слову ["ворожити"](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=15903&page=526), у значені передбачати майбутнє.***